# vNext Build definition to build Visual Studio 2005 solution in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, build, definition

I need to configure a build definition in TFS 2017 for a solution that is developed in VS 2005.
The agent server that execute Build tasks is configured with Windows Server 2012 R2, and it's installed VS 2005.
In a build definition, I have tried with a command line task, but it remains executing the compilation and it is canceled by time-out

Can someone please reference me documentation or indicate me how to do it?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Audberto

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you'll be able to get the "Visual Studio Build" task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=tfs-2017 working, but you may look at the MSBuild task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=tfs-2017 since you have a little more control.
Since 2005 (along with 2008 and 2010) are end of life, I don't think you'll get much support from Microsoft to support your scenario in the built in tasks.